# {kdenlive} Render to webm and mp4 keeps failing: AVStream.codec error

Tags: audio, video, codec, kdenlive, melt

I'm trying to render **39 minutes long** video made of a few joined **.MOV 1080p Canon clips**. I apply a few effects to some of them, the list is (unfortunately, I don't not their exact English name): *audio and video fade in and out, stereo channels balance, Normalize, Volume (keyframeable).*

When I try to render the video, it starts to render normally and then it fails with the following message:

```
 Rendering /.../.../...... failed.

    [webm @ 0x7fc780000ec0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead. [webm @ 0x7fc780000ec0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use
    AVStream.codecpar instead.
    melt: ../vp8/common/treecoder.c:92: vp8_tree_probs_from_distribution: Predicting „tot
```

I've tried rendering to free WebM and MP4 both have the same problem and I don't think trying other formats would help... I've tried Googling, but nothing seems to be a solution to my problem... I've tried applying those effect to some other (but shorter) .MOV footage, everything rendered fine. So I literally don't have a single idea where the problem could be...

Is it a bug? Missing library?

Any help would be highly appreciated...

```
OS: openSUSE 15.0
Kernel: x86_64 Linux 4.12.14-lp150.12.28-default
Shell: bash
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: KDE 5.45.0 / Plasma 5.12.6
CPU: Intel Core i7-4800MQ @ 8x 3.7GHz [52.0°C]
GPU: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile
RAM: 15638MiB

Kdenlive version: 18.08.3
MLT version: 6.12.0
```